# GA4 - report API - php client - filter error

Tags: php, api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Im try to apply a filter  on a query, and getting an **fatal error**
here is the source code:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\OrderBy;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\OrderBy\MetricOrderBy;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Filter;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Filter\StringFilter;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\FilterExpression;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Filter\StringFilter\MatchType;
$property_id = XXXX;
$response_cpc = $client->runReport([
'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
'dateRanges' => [
new DateRange([
'start_date' => $_GET["date"],
'end_date' => $_GET["date"],
]),
],

'dimensions' => [new Dimension(
[
'name' => 'firstUserSourceMedium',
]
)],[new Dimension(
    [
        'name' => 'firstUserCampaignName',
    ]
)
],
'metrics' => [new Metric(
[
'name' => 'sessions',
]
),new Metric(
[
'name' => 'bounceRate',
]
),
new Metric(
[
'name' => 'conversions:Newsletter_signup',
]
),
new Metric(
[
'name' => 'screenPageViewsPerSession',
]
),
new Metric(
[
'name' => 'transactions',
]
),
new Metric(
[
'name' => 'conversions:go_to_amazon',
]
)

],
'dimensionFilter' => [new FilterExpression (
            [
                'filter' => [new Filter(
                    [
                        'field_name' => 'firstUserSourceMedium',
                        'string_filter' => [new StringFilter([
                            'match_type' => Filter\StringFilter\MatchType::BEGINS_WITH,
                             'value' => 'cpc',
                            'case_sensitive'=> false,
                            ]
                    )]
                    ]
                )]
            ]
        )],
    'limit'=> 25,
    'orderBys' =>[ new OrderBy([
    'metric' => new MetricOrderBy([
        'metric_name' =>'sessions']
        ),
    'desc'=>true,
    ])],

]);

print_r($response_cpc);
```

and here is the error I'm getting:

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Expect Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Filter\StringFilter. in /home/Server1/xagyrxxhed/public_html/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/GPBUtil.php:198 Stack trace: #0 /home/Server1/xagyrxxhed/public_html/vendor/google/analytics-data/src/V1beta/Filter.php(116): Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBUtil::checkMessage() #1 /home/Server1/xagyrxxhed/public_html/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php(1082): Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Filter->setStringFilter() #2 /home/Server1/xagyrxxhed/public_html/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/Message.php(80): Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message->mergeFromArray() #3 /home/Server1/xagyrxxhed/public_html/vendor/google/analytics-data/src/V1beta/Filter.php(54): Google\Protobuf\Internal\Message->__construct() #4 /home/Server1/xagyrxxhed/public_html/quickstart.php(280): Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Filter->__construc in /home/Server1/xagyrxxhed/public_html/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/GPBUtil.php on line 198

Any help ?

Comment: It looks right to me, but can you make sure that the namespaces and class names are correctly specified?

Comment: i believe that they are correct. see the head of the code, I insert  namespaces I import.,

Comment: OK. found the issues:
1- memory my server did  not have enough  memory.. fixed that
2- found some issues on the  and fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with:
1- memory increase
2- change in the code: Remove some [

```
'dimensionFilter' => new FilterExpression (
        ``[
            'filter' => new Filter(
                [
                    'field_name' => 'firstUserSourceMedium',
                    'string_filter' => new Filter\StringFilter([
                            'match_type' => 4,
                            'value' => 'cpc',
                            'case_sensitive'=> false,
                        ]
                    )
                ]
            )
        ]
    ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).