# PHP Google Analytics Data API V1 (Beta) (GA4) : BetaAnalyticsDataGapicClient::runReport() must be of the type array

Tags: google-analytics, google-api

I am trying to fetch data from G4A using this guide:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/main/analyticsdata/quickstart.php

Here is my code:

```
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;

//use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Client\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\RunReportRequest;

$client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClient([
    'credentials' => json_decode(file_get_contents($KEY_FILE_LOCATION ), true)
]);

`// [START analyticsdata_run_report]
// Make an API call.
$request = (new RunReportRequest())
    ->setProperty('properties/' . $property_id)
    ->setDateRanges([
        new DateRange([
            'start_date' => '2020-03-31',
            'end_date' => 'today',
        ]),
    ])
        ->setDimensions([new Dimension([
            'name' => 'city',
         ]),
    ])
    ->setMetrics([new Metric([
        'name' => 'activeUsers',
        ])
    ]);

//$request_2 = [
//    'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
//    'dateRanges' => [
//        'start_date' => '2020-03-31',
//        'end_date' => 'today'
//    ]
//];


$response = $client->runReport($request);


// [END analyticsdata_run_report]

// [START analyticsdata_run_report_response]
// Print results of an API call.
print 'Report result: ' . PHP_EOL;

foreach ($response->getRows() as $row) {
    print $row->getDimensionValues()[0]->getValue()
        . ' ' . $row->getMetricValues()[0]->getValue() . PHP_EOL;
    // [END analyticsdata_run_report_response]
}
```

And here is my error output:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Gapic\BetaAnalyticsDataGapicClient::runReport() must be of the type array, object given, called in /var/www/app/httpdocs/backend/cron/g4a_testing.php on line 49 and defined in /var/www/app/vendor/google/analytics-data/src/V1beta/Gapic/BetaAnalyticsDataGapicClient.php on line 994 TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Gapic\BetaAnalyticsDataGapicClient::runReport() must be of the type array, object given, called in /var/www/app/httpdocs/backend/cron/g4a_testing.php on line 49 in /var/www/app/vendor/google/analytics-data/src/V1beta/Gapic/BetaAnalyticsDataGapicClient.php on line 994 Call Stack: 0.0003 385000 1. {main}() /var/www/app/httpdocs/backend/cron/g4a_testing.php:0 0.1072 3777680 2. Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient->runReport() /var/www/app/httpdocs/backend/cron/g4a_testing.php:49
```

I tried hardcoding the request data like in this page: https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-data#installation

```
$request_2 = [
    'property' => 'properties/' . $property_id,
    'dateRanges' => [
        'start_date' => '2020-03-31',
        'end_date' => 'today'
    ]
];


$response = $client->runReport($request_2);
```

And here is my error output:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Expect Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange. in /var/www/app/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/GPBUtil.php on line 198 Exception: Expect Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange. in /var/www/app/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/GPBUtil.php on line 198 Call Stack: 0.0003 385000 1. {main}() /var/www/app/httpdocs/backend/cron/g4a_testing.php:0 0.1369 3778104 2. Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient->runReport() /var/www/app/httpdocs/backend/cron/g4a_testing.php:49 0.1370 3779360 3. Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\RunReportRequest->setDateRanges() /var/www/app/vendor/google/analytics-data/src/V1beta/Gapic/BetaAnalyticsDataGapicClient.php:1012 0.1370 3779384 4. Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBUtil::checkRepeatedField() /var/www/app/vendor/google/analytics-data/src/V1beta/RunReportRequest.php:332 0.1371 3779496 5. Google\Protobuf\Internal\RepeatedField->offsetSet() /var/www/app/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/GPBUtil.php:210 0.1371 3779520 6. Google\Protobuf\Internal\GPBUtil::checkMessage() /var/www/app/vendor/google/protobuf/src/Google/Protobuf/Internal/RepeatedField.php:187
```

Comment: Update: got positive results from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76326394/ga4-report-api-php-client-filter-error?rq=2